# How to move SQL info from one DB to another

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to migrate SQL From one script to another, Namely only one part of it, but they use different "Code".

Basically im trying to move information for "States" which is held as a number in side both DB's. But the numbers of course are different, For instance Arizona's in one is 12 but the other is 3425.

Im trying to find a way to First match the Customer ID which is the same in both, then grab the Number from one DB and then convert it to the number it is in the new DB and place it in the correct area in said DB.

But my skills with SQL are very lacking and i can't find a reasonable solution.

Scripts in use:
Old - CRE Loaded 4.2.1a
New - OpenCart (Current Version)

EDIT

Here is my best at explaining the DB structure, excuse me if its not the best explanation of how the DB works:

Here is the Old DB Structure for the Tables that are involved:

address_book - Holds customer Information, State number is held in the Colum entry_zone_id in number format, also the Country number is held in entry_country_id also in number format, the "Zone ID" is based off of the "Country ID" depending on the country.

zones - Holds State and Country ID Information, the Example:
for arizona the zone_id is 4, the zone_country_id is 223 (For USA), the zone_code is AZ, and the Zone_name is Arizona

customers - This holds the main customer information, not includeing address info, customers_id is of course the customers ID Number which corrosponds with the same Customer ID in the table address_book. customers_default_address_id also corrosponds with the ID in address_book.

Now as for the new DB:

oc_address - address_id and customer_id mark the customers ID number. country_id tells which country they are in, Its in number format. zone_id holds the state's DB number.

oc_zone - "zone_id" holds the Zones ID, "country_id" holds the countrys ID number, such as USA is. "name" is the state name. "code" state or country code. Example:
Arizona in the DB shows like this:
zone_id=3616, country_id=223, name=Arizona, code=AZ, status=1(shows that its used)

One that may also be needed to know is this one:
oc_country - holds country info, country_id holds country code, name is the name of the country, isa_code_2 and iso_code_3 are the country ISO codes.

i hope this is of use.

Comment: set up a translation table that does the 12<->3425 mapping. then you can do an `insert ... select from`, joining that translation table.

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: `create table translation (newtable int, oldtable int)`. `insert into newtable select ... translation.newtable from oldtable join translation on oldtable.state = translation.oldtable`

Comment: would you be able to join the tables using the state's name? (convert both to lowercase maybe)
otherwise can you show/explain to us all the columns in your two tables.

Comment: edited post to show my best at explaining it.